# How to get a command's category?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I was making a customised help command, which is completely automated, i.e. I don't have to make a help command for each command on my own, a function does that whenever I call the help command.

The function works. What doesn't work is the help dashboard. For example, if I use `help <category>` I have to write the name of each command to give the command list. I can loop through the commands using `client.commands` but that won't categorize them. Is there a way to check the commands category?

After typing all this, I do realise that this information was completely unnecessary. Here is the summary:

**HOW DO I GET A COMMAND'S CATEGORY?**

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the `Command.cog` attribute

```py
for command in client.commands:
    category = command.cog # Can be None
```

#### Reference:

- [`Command.cog`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Command.cog)